# Can I run git-p4 commands via JGit?

Tags: jgit

I'm developing a Java application using JGit and need to sync a p4 repository with a git repository.

I don't like idea of using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git p4 sync");`. 
Can I use JGit to do the job? Or any other Java library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you need to resort to executing C Git or find some other means.

There is no support in JGit for syncing with p4 repositories.

Comment: yeah, didn't find it in JGit sources.